# vertically aligning an absolutely positioned element and psedo element

Tags: css

I have the following code : i have a few questions about this code and it is pertaining to the line - height property given to the psedo elements , have a look at the code .

HTML:

```
<div class="side">
     <nav class="dr-menu">
          <div class="dr-trigger"><span class="dr-icon dr-icon-menu"></span><a class="dr-label">Account</a></div>
     </nav>
</div>   <!-- end of side -->
```

CSS code :

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: red;
}
.dr-menu {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    min-width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 2.5;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 2em;
}

.dr-menu > div  {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.dr-menu > div .dr-icon {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 150%;
    line-height: 1.6em;
    padding: 0 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.dr-menu.dr-menu-open > div .dr-icon {
    color: #60a773;
    left: 100%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    transform: translateX(-100%);
}

/*critical*/
.dr-icon:before, 
.dr-icon:after {
    position: relative;
    font-family:  FontAwesome;
    speak: none;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.dr-menu > div .dr-label {
    padding-left: 3em;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    color: #60a773;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 700;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 2.75;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease;
    transition: all 0.2s ease;
}

.dr-menu.dr-menu-open > div .dr-label {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-90%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-90%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-90%);
    transform: translateY(-90%);
}

.dr-menu ul .dr-icon:before {
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.dr-icon-menu:before {
    content: "\f0c9";
}
```

if you zoom in and have a look at the css and check the following declaration

```
.dr-menu > div .dr-icon
```

Jsfiddle [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gautamz07/toemstaz/)

you will see that there is a line-height given of 1.6em and actually if you take off the line height property and instead change the top to -15px , and the alignment will be perfect as earlier , so why has the author preferred line-height(responsiveness maybe ? compared to doing top:-15px ? ) ? i don't quite understand the usage of line height for aligning elements together though i am aware that line-height can be used for vertical alignment .  or  is it just some really intelligent math applied in this example that i am totally missing ?

NOTE:

the code works just fine . my question is why use the line-height property for vertical alignment ? and how did the author of the code know that 1.6em exactly would vertically align both the elements ? 
or is there some careful math applied that i am totally missing ?

Comment: I think you want to this http://jsfiddle.net/toemstaz/1/

Comment: @RohitAzad Bhai ! the code works just fine . my question is why use the line-height property for vertical alignment ? and how did the author of the code know that 1.6em exactly would vertically align both the elements ?

Comment: looks like he has given `line-height` depending upon the `font-size`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes Thank you Bhava-Majai(Brother) from goa ! but i need a little detailed explanation . also , font-size of what ? u mean the base font-size set to .dr-menu ?

Comment: font size of this `.dr-menu > div .dr-icon {font-size: 150%;}`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes , I Still Don't get it , Let me make it simple , if i take off the line-height:1.6em , the icon kind of floats down , why does that happen ? and why does adding 1.6 bring it up again ? refer to the original fiddle i posted . Thanks .

Comment: [screenshot](http://s23.postimg.org/u84kdpmrv/Screen_Shot_2014_11_03_at_6_09_43_pm.png) check the image i have linked the `line-height` is inherited form parent